# ERROR TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate') when import my component in child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have Created a collapse menu component and import into it onother component But the screen is not navigate. it showing error of **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')** . I am unable to navigate my screen by the label name.

Collapse menu Code

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  LayoutAnimation,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import Font from '../constant/fonts';
import Color from '../constant/colors';
import fontF from '../styles/fontfamily';
import Icon from '../styles/icons';

import {heightToDp, widthToDp} from '../constant/utils';
import Size from '../constant/sizes';
import Card from './Cards/card';
import {Divider} from 'react-native-elements';
class CollapseMenu extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('navigation', this.props);
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      expanded: false,
    };
    this.handleCollapse = this.handleCollapse.bind(this);
  }

  handleCollapse() {
    const {expanded} = this.state;
    this.setState({expanded: !expanded});
  }
  handleRoute(label) {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.navigation.navigate(label);
  }

  render() {
    const {expanded} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleCollapse}>
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
              <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                <Icon.SimpleLineIcons name={this.props.item.icon} size={20} />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                <Text style={[styles.labelStyle]}>
                  {this.props.item.title.toUpperCase()}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                <Icon.SimpleLineIcons
                  name={expanded ? 'arrow-up' : 'arrow-down'}
                  size={20}
                  color={Color.grayDark}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {this.props.item.subarr.map((child, j) => (
          <View>
            {expanded ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.handleRoute.bind(this, child.label)}>
                <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
                  <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                    {/* <Icon.FontAwesome
                            name={r.icon}
                            size={20}
                            color={Color.gray}
                          /> */}
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                    <Text style={[styles.labelStyle]}>
                      {child.label.toUpperCase()}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.barIcon}>{/* <Text>icon</Text> */}</View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

});

export default CollapseMenu;
```

And use this Component by passing the Data like:

```
 <CollapseMenu item={data}/>
```

Comment: which `react navigation` version are you using?

Comment: @NileshPatel v5

Comment: ok. can you share parent component code?

Comment: problem is you are using class component '`CollapseMenu`.

Comment: @NileshPatel can you explain me in brief?

Comment: `navigation` prop is available only to the route components. any other child component, you can not access 'navigation` props... with v5, there is hook `useNavigation` which you can use to navigate but that can be used in function component only.

Comment: `<NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>` these are all route components

Comment: are you using `CollapseMenu` in route component?

Answer (score 2):

With react-navigation v5, only api we have to navigate from nested child /non-route components is `useNavigate` hook which can be used only in function components.

As per [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation), work around to use in class component is to create a wrapper function component.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  LayoutAnimation,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

import Font from '../constant/fonts';
import Color from '../constant/colors';
import fontF from '../styles/fontfamily';
import Icon from '../styles/icons';

import {heightToDp, widthToDp} from '../constant/utils';
import Size from '../constant/sizes';
import Card from './Cards/card';
import {Divider} from 'react-native-elements';
class CollapseMenu extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('navigation', this.props);
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      expanded: false,
    };
    this.handleCollapse = this.handleCollapse.bind(this);
  }

  handleCollapse() {
    const {expanded} = this.state;
    this.setState({expanded: !expanded});
  }
  handleRoute(label) {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.navigation.navigate(label);
  }

  render() {
    const {expanded} = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleCollapse}>
          <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
            <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
              <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                <Icon.SimpleLineIcons name={this.props.item.icon} size={20} />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                <Text style={[styles.labelStyle]}>
                  {this.props.item.title.toUpperCase()}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                <Icon.SimpleLineIcons
                  name={expanded ? 'arrow-up' : 'arrow-down'}
                  size={20}
                  color={Color.grayDark}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        {this.props.item.subarr.map((child, j) => (
          <View>
            {expanded ? (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.handleRoute.bind(this, child.label)}>
                <View style={[styles.sidebarDesign]}>
                  <View style={styles.barIcon}>
                    {/* <Icon.FontAwesome
                            name={r.icon}
                            size={20}
                            color={Color.gray}
                          /> */}
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.barLabel}>
                    <Text style={[styles.labelStyle]}>
                      {child.label.toUpperCase()}
                    </Text>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.barIcon}>{/* <Text>icon</Text> */}</View>
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ) : null}
          </View>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

});

// Wrap and export 
function CollapseMenuWrapper(props) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return <CollapseMenu {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
export default CollapseMenuWrapper;
```